# Boot configuration with corrupt startup on Medion Notebook E4242

Tags: windows, boot, bios

I have erased part of the operating system by mistake and am unable to get into the system at all. Can anyone help me to boot from a usb onto a Medion Notebook E4242.

Answer (score 0):

1.Firstly,download and install the windows ADK.
How to download and install the windows ADK, we can refer to this article:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/download-winpe--windows-pe

2.Secondly,create a bootable USB, CD, or DVD.
Step 1: create working files.
Step 2: create bootable media.
To learn how to create a bootable WinPE USB drive, we can refer this article:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive

The following two links are video that we can refer to:
[How to Create Windows 7 WinPE Boot Disk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qb5jGaKnsw)
[How to Create Windows 10 WinPE Boot Disk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zDFhSuBWaM)